# azure face api c#

Tags: c#, azure

Как максимально просто, реализовать сравнение двух лиц на сходство используя сервис azure face

Мне нужно реализовать то что у них на сайте в примере
https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/services/cognitive-services/face/

То есть два изображение и ответ один и тот же человек или разные люди

Подскажите каким методом реализуется данная функция

Comment: Прям под примерами вас спрашивают "Хотите создать подобное?" [Документация >](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/csharp). Что конкретно у вас не получилось из данной документации?

Comment: Там предлагается в первом пример просто нахождение лица (рамка на лицо), второй  показывает как сделать это в форме, третий собирает атрибуты , и в четвертом показан пример класификации по людям (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtoidentifyfacesinimage), но я не понял как я могу получить, или вывести из полученного  `bool ` одни  и тот же человек или нет

Comment: Ну это обычный [API](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523a), который на вход требует 2 faceid (полученные через [Detect](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236). На выходе получаете isIdentical - bool значение обозначающее одинаковое лицо или нет.

Comment: У них также есть библиотека со своими методами - `Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face`. Пример использования опять же в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/cognitive-services/face/tutorials/faceapiincsharptutorial).

Comment: Благодарю, такой ответ мне и нужен был

Comment: Ладно, я дурак приведите пожалуйста пример

Comment: Walker, а смысл вам отвечать, если вы не принимаете ответы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала подготовим необходимое:

- Библиотека `Newtonsoft.Json` для удобной работы с JSON объектом.
- Ключ API (пробный получаем [тут](https://azure.microsoft.com/try/cognitive-services/?api=face-api), выдает 2 ключа и сервер, который их принимает), заносим для удобства в константу:

  ```
  const string Key = "12345678901234567890";
  ```
- Далее для удобства вынесем отдельно сервер (локацию) для API:

  ```
  const string Location = "westcentralus";
  ```
- Теперь нам нужно 2 API адреса:

  - [Detect](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236) - определяет что именно за изображение и дает на 24 часа id для него.

    ```
    static readonly string DetectApi = $"https://{Location}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect";
    ```
  - [Verify](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523a) - сверяет два изображения по их Id.

    ```
    static readonly string VerifyApi = $"https://{Location}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/verify";
    ```
- Теперь нам нужно сделать простенький метод для отправки POST на сервер, он будет принимать объект для дальнейшей сериализации в JSON, указывать ключ в заголовке (авторизация), отправлять и выдавать ответ:

  ```
  private static async Task<string> SendRequest(string url, object data)
  {
      string result;

      using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Key);

          var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

          var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
          result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }

      return result;
  }
  ```
- Теперь для удобства создадим класс, который будет содержать url изображения и его Id:

  ```
  class Image
  {
      public Image(string url)
      {
          Url = url;
      }

      public string Url { get; set; }
      public string Id { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Ну и последнее, что нам понадобиться - некая коллекция наших картинок:

  ```
  var images = new List<Image>
  {
      new Image("https://st.kp.yandex.net/images/actor_iphone/iphone360_6793.jpg"),
      new Image("https://images2.cosmopolitan.ru/upload/img_cache/f15/f15b62dc9a5b8584b1bc87b50ce25e83_fitted_740x0.jpg")
  };
  ```

---

С подготовкой закончили, давайте теперь получим те самые Id изображений, для этого мы просто пройдемся по коллекции и для каждого объекта выполним запрос на DetectApi адрес:

```
foreach (var image in images)
{
    var data = new { url = image.Url };
    var result = await SendRequest(DetectApi, data);
    var json = JArray.Parse(result);
    image.Id = (string) json[0]["faceId"];
}
```

- `var data = new { url = image.Url };` - формируем объект (анонимный тип), который будет в методе `SendRequest` переведен в Json вида `{ "url": "http://example.com/1.jpg" }`.
- `var result = await SendRequest(DetectApi, data);` - в результате получаем ответ от API с JSON объектом (Array), который будет содержать необходимый нам  `faceId` и др. данные.
- `var json = JArray.Parse(result);` - парсим результат в JArray.
- `image.Id = (string) json[0]["faceId"];` - так, как это массив с 1 объектом, то берем из первого объекта `faceId`, переводим в string и заносим в наш `image`.

Результатом всех этих действий у нас будет в массиве `images` id у каждого изображения.

---

Отлично, имея Id, нам остается только сверить их через `VerifyApi`, напишем простой метод, который будет принимать 2 string (Id), отправит запрос и результат вернет нам:

```
private static async Task<JObject> Verify(string faceId1, string faceId2)
{
    var data = new {faceId1, faceId2};
    var result = await SendRequest(VerifyApi, data);
    return JObject.Parse(result);
}
```

Вызываем:

```
var verify = await Verify(images[0].Id, images[1].Id);
```

Выведем данные:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Результат: {verify["isIdentical"]}");
Console.WriteLine($"Уверен на {verify["confidence"]}");
```

В итоге получаем:

```
Результат: True
Уверен на 0,61441
```

Марафет (в виде отлова ошибок и расстановки всего по своим местам) наведете сами, делал почти на коленки, но вроде как работает.

Удачи в изучении C#!